# How to display image on an server to iOS device by php, swift

Tags: php, swift, server, uiimageview, uiimage

I plan to display an image stored on server local(macbook) on my iphone for testing app. The image stored in path: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/imagestock`. I write web-service by PHP to display image on browse(like an URL), here is server code :

**displayimage.php**

```
<?php
$dir = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/imagestock';
$file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

if (file_exists($dir) == false)
{
    echo 'Directory "', $dir, '" not found!';
}
else
{
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

    echo "<img src='img.php?name=photo-37.jpg' height='280' width='360' />";

}
?>
```

**img.php**

```
 <?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $mimes = array
    (
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));

    $file = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/imagestock/'.$name;
    header('content-type: '. $mimes[$ext]);
    header('content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'";');
    readfile($file);
?>
```

I just test and see image clear on my browse, in my client project to display image on `UIImageView`, my code here :

```
func load_image()
{

    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.2/MyWebService/api/displayimage.php") else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
        }

        if let imageData = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageStock.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

There no error happen, but the image not display. So, how can i resolve the problem? I've tried some ways, but didn't work. I think error with server code? Someone can help me?

Comment: check the  result from this url `http://192.168.1.2/MyWebService/api/displayimage.php` in any browser

Comment: It display image normally safari, chrome

Comment: displayimage.php output a html img tag, may be you should try your img.php cause it returns only the image.

Comment: You must get the image directly from path and not through html tag ex: 
 `http://192.168.1.2/imagestock/img.png`

Comment: Not sure understand your answer @mim

Comment: How do i made this URL http://192.168.1.2/imagestock/img.png ? @a.masri

Comment: finally, i got the answer, thank all guys

Answer (score 0):

within your load_image() function you try to load image from server that gives you the image in data form.but this approach will try to download image each time when you call the function.
You should get only URL of image in load_image() function.
then using the Kingfisher third party you should show the image.as below

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image") // e.g. url_of_your_image  = http://192.168.1.2/imagestock/img.png
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

It will only download image once and maintain it redundancy automatically.
how to import kingfisher in you code ,can see [here](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the answer. No need to make server side code, simple move folder `imagestock` into folder `htdocs`, look like this

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagestock
```

Change url above http://192.168.1.2/MyWebService/api/displayimage.php
to http://192.168.1.2/imagestock/photo-37.jpg in client code